# Failed to Create volume: This IO profile requires a minimum replication factor of 2 nodes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

volume creation failed while installing the statefulset.

Events:

```
9s          Warning   ProvisioningFailed   persistentvolumeclaim/kafka-vol-kafka-0                     Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "hello-sc": rpc error: code = Internal desc = Failed to create volume: This IO profile requires a minimum replication factor of 2 nodes
```

PVC

```
kubectl get pvc -n hello
NAME                STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
hello-vol-hello-0     Pending                                      hell-sc     44m
```

Storage class definition:

```yaml
Name:            hello-sc
IsDefaultClass:  Yes
Annotations:     kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"allowVolumeExpansion":true,"apiVersion":"storage.k8s.io/v1","kind":"StorageClass","metadata":{"annotations":{"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"true"},"name":"hello-sc"},"parameters":{"cow_ondemand":"true","disable_io_profile_protection":"true","fs":"ext4","io_profile":"db_remote","priority_io":"high","repl":"1"},"provisioner":"kubernetes.io/portworx-volume","reclaimPolicy":"Delete","volumeBindingMode":"Immediate"}
,storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class=true
Provisioner:           kubernetes.io/portworx-volume
Parameters:            cow_ondemand=true,disable_io_profile_protection=true,fs=ext4,io_profile=db_remote,priority_io=high,repl=1
AllowVolumeExpansion:  True
MountOptions:          <none>
ReclaimPolicy:         Delete
VolumeBindingMode:     Immediate
Events:                <none>
```

Installing the statefulset with PVC. The volume should be created, even with replication factor 1.

Answer (score 1):

The error **Failed to create volume: This IO profile requires a minimum replication factor of 2 nodes** suggesting that to create volume IO profile requires replication factor of at least 2 nodes.

As mentioned in the [document](https://support.purestorage.com/Solutions/Kafka/Best_Practices_for_Apache_Kafka_running_on_Kubernetes_with_Portworx) on Best practises for Apache kafka running on kubernetes with portworx :

> Kafka, being designed as a distributed and horizontally scalable streaming system, relies on the replication factor of topic-partitions to achieve higher availability of the data if a broker has to fail. As such for production readiness, **you should never run Kafka with the default replication factor of 1 even if you are running the application on Kubernetes with Portworx.  The general recommendation is to use either 2 or 3 for the replication factor which allows either 1 or 2 broker failures and still have access to the data.**
>
> Portworx enables high availability of the application data through replication at the storage level.  Portworx allows you to set the replication between 1 and 3 where 3 offers the highest level of data protection and availability.

You can also refer to this github [link](https://github.com/thanos-io/thanos/issues/3194) and this [document](https://docs.portworx.com/portworx-enterprise/operations/operate-kubernetes/storage-operations/create-snapshots/skinnysnaps) for more information.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. I am using the lab for testing, so 2 replicas may not be required for me.

Answer (score 0):

explicitly specifying the `io_profile` is causing the issue.

[image: io profile values]

Problematic definition:

```yaml
allowVolumeExpansion: true
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"allowVolumeExpansion":true,"apiVersion":"storage.k8s.io/v1","kind":"StorageClass","metadata":{"annotations":{"storagecla
ss.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"true"},"name":"hello-sc"},"parameters":{"cow_ondemand":"true","disable_io_profile_protecti
on":"true","fs":"ext4","io_profile":"db_remote","priority_io":"high","repl":"1"},"provisioner":"kubernetes.io/portworx-volume","
reclaimPolicy":"Delete","volumeBindingMode":"Immediate"}
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2022-12-07T08:15:45Z"
  name: hello-sc
  resourceVersion: "256593028"
  uid: 557e55db-3440-4c2b-a5ee-842d09c1e7d2
parameters:
  cow_ondemand: "true"
  disable_io_profile_protection: "true"
  fs: ext4
  io_profile: db_remote
  priority_io: high
  repl: "1"
provisioner: kubernetes.io/portworx-volume
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

Working defintion:

```yaml
allowVolumeExpansion: true
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"allowVolumeExpansion":true,"apiVersion":"storage.k8s.io/v1beta1","kind":"StorageClass","metadata":{"annotations":{"stora
geclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"true"},"name":"hello-sc"},"parameters":{"fs":"ext4","repl":"1"},"provisioner":"kubern
etes.io/portworx-volume"}
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2022-04-08T11:32:23Z"
  name: hello-sc
  resourceVersion: "36880"
  uid: db05d65c-33ae-4feb-986d-b7e92b3c077a
parameters:
  fs: ext4
  repl: "1"
provisioner: kubernetes.io/portworx-volume
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```